# What are pitfalls of porting source code from Visual C++ to GCC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, portability

It is well known that GCC implements C++ standard much more strictly than Visual C++.
Frankly speaking, Visual C++ just doesn't follow C++ standard well.

And this is continuous headache for developers that primarily develop with Visual C++ but need  the code to be portable and compiled at least with GCC.

Some of Visual C++ language misconducts are documented in [MSDN Nonstandard Behavior topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x84h5b78.aspx) in practically there is a lot of other undocumented cases.

The idea of this post is to log all known compatibility issues for VC++ against GCC (the most popular C++ compilers). Issue is raised when some code snippet is compiled with Visual C++ without warnings (W4 level) and doesn't (produces error or warning) with GCC.

Please note that it's only for standard C++ issues, Microsoft specific language extensions like `__super` or `__forceinline` are out of scope.

Proposed format of issue description:

- Code snippet (compiled OK with Visual C++)
- GCC error or warning it produces
- Both compilers version to reproduce
- Reference to violated C++ Standard statement (optional, can be added later)
- Solution (how to change code to be successfully compiled both by VC++ and GCC)

Comment: stick to Standard C++ and most probable you'll avoid these pitfalls.

Comment: @40two Even sticking to standard C++ won't work very well. As the OP said Visual Studio is really bad at following the standard, and creating code that works on both is a restricted set of the actual standard. That or a bunch of '#ifdef __MSVC__'

Comment: @Smith_61 notice the word "most probable" in my statement.

Comment: @40two Standard contains about 1300 pages of non-obvious technical text. It's not easy just "to stick" to it, so it's not an option for normal developer.

Comment: @Rost "Stick to standard C++": is not interpreted as read the whole C++ standard, but rather write C++ standard compliant code. Unless of course, you write a C++ compiler. Then you need to read all the 1300 pages.

Comment: @40two There are several cases when it's not obvious that the code actually violates standard (especially if you didn't get it by heart). The intent of this question is to reveal and document such cases.

Comment: This question is way too broad to be suitable for SO. In order for it to be answered in full, code snippets and resultant error message as well as alternative solutions would need to be posted for every single non-standard compliant feature. An entire website or wiki would be needed to do justice to this topic.

Comment: @JBentley I see no problem here. Several answers can be posted and updated in order to improve the info. There is no other way to perfection.

Comment: Questions that can't be properly answered in the Stack Overflow format aren't on topic. You're asking for dozens if not hundreds of answers be posted, with no answer being the correct one.

Comment: My experience is the opposite of the assertion at the top of the post.  Many times, I've seen gcc accept broken code that MSVC correctly flags as non-standard.  But it's rather pointless to compile a list of differences since both compilers are moving quickly, and the standard is updating quicker now than before.  MSVC tends to be a little behind on language features but a little ahead on library features.  Neither is yet 100% C++11 compliant and the C++14 standard is now in play.  And then there's clang/LLVM.  Anyway this is too broad for SO.

Comment: GCC is equally guilty of allowing non-standard extensions.  Lets all kinds of C99 code leak into C++ files, even though they aren't supported by C++.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Actually it doesn't matter how quickly compilers and standards are moving. The real world is much more conservative and far from frontline. Dozen of companies still don't use C++11 in production. And supporting VS2008 and GCC 4.1.2 is still not rare case.

Comment: @Rost:  It matters in that it makes this question even more broad because it's not just MSVC vs. GCC with respect to a certain standard.  Instead it's a multi-dimensional matrix.  And, the opening claim is that MSVC doesn't follow the standard well, without specifying which version of MSVC and which version of the standard, so the claim is virtually impossible to evaluate.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty broad question, but here are some things I've run into:

Wrong point of declaration:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
  S(int) { std::cout << "Incorrect\n"; }
  S(S const &) { std::cout << "Correct\n"; }
};

int s;

int main() {
  S s(s);
}
```

Output should be "Correct", but Visual Studio's (all versions) output is "Incorrect".

---

Incorrect generation of copy assignment and copy initialization:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B {
    B &operator = (B &) { std::cout << "Correct\n"; return *this; }
    template<typename T>
    B &operator = (T &) { std::cout << "Incorrect\n"; return *this; }
};

struct D : B {};

int main() {
    D d;
    d = d;
}
```

This was fixed in Visual Studio 2012 I think. Before 2012 VS's output was "Incorrect".

---

Two-phase name lookup:

```
#include <iostream>

static void foo(long) {
  std::cout << "Correct\n";
}

template<typename T>
void bar(T t) {
  foo(t);
}

static void foo(int) {
  std::cout << "Incorrect\n";
}

int main() {
  bar(1);
}
```

The output should be "Correct", but Visual Studio's (all versions so far) output is "Incorrect".

---

Alternative tokens don't work:

```
int main() <% %>
```

This program should compile and run, but no version of Visual Studio successfully compiles it.

---

user defined type definitions inside for-loop initializer clause:

```
int main() {
  for (struct {int a;} a = {0}; a.a < 10; ++(a.a)) {

  }
}
```

This is legal but VS does not allow it.

---

All these compile and run correctly under gcc and clang going back quite a few versions. Gcc used to have problems with two-phase lookup, but not for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

**Code snippet, compiled OK with VC++ 2013:**

```
struct X
{
   template <class T> struct Z {};

   template <> struct Z<int> {}; // Source of problem
};
```

**GCC error produced (4.7.2):** `error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope`

**Violated standard clause:** `14.7.3 Explicit specialization, p.2 - An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace enclosing the specialized template.`

**Solution:** use partial specialization instead of explicit one:

```
struct X
{
    template <class T, class MakeItPartial=void> struct Z {};

    template <class MakeItPartial> struct Z<int, MakeItPartial> {};
};
```

Or if possible just move it to enclosing namespace scope:

```
struct X
{
    template <class T> struct Z {};
};

template <> struct X::Z<int> {};
```